# InterpND for one dimension

Tags: openmdao

I'm trying to use the function InterpND from openmdao.components.interp_util.interp.

No problem using it for multidimensional data - I can interpolate a 3-D tensor without problems. However I'd also like to use for 1-D data. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I try to do something really simple like

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.components.interp_util.interp import InterpND

x = np.array([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.])
y = x**2
f = InterpND(points=x, values=y)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: There are 5 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions
```

Looking at the InterpND source code it seems like I SHOULD be able to just have x and y as simple 1-D arrays.

```
Parameters
        ----------
        points : ndarray or tuple of ndarray of float, with shapes (m1, ), ..., (mn, )
            The points defining the regular grid in n dimensions.  For 1D interpolation, this
            can be an ndarray.
        values : array_like, shape (m1, ..., mn, ...)
```

x is a 1D ndarray, y is also a 1D nd array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in OpenMDAO V3.7.0 related to the input error checking. Here is a workaround. If you put the 1-D table points into a list, it works without error:

```
 f = InterpND(points=[x], values=y)
```

Comment: oh yes I had found that out. However it won't work for an array of input values. I'll just use the scipy functions for now

Comment: You actually need an extra dimension for the interpolated coordinate as well, so it would be `computed = f.interpolate(np.array([[2.5], [3.5]]))` if you want to interpolate at 2.5 and 3.5.  It is kind of a pain there too, and the bug story will look at making this more convenient for 1D usage with everything flat.